# How to loop through the array and bring values based on conditions?

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script

I have an array of objects like [{email=anu@g.com , plan = free} {email=anu3@g.com , plan = paid}]

Suppose email is x, which is basically condition. Need to check the condition that 'email' is match to x then bring the value of  'plan'.

How do I achieve above that.

Comment: Please try to make an attempt to solve the problem yourself before asking for help. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: This is not an object `{email=anu@g.com , plan = free}`

Comment: Why is this question tagged [json]? An array of objects is an array of objects. A JSON representation of an array of objects is a text string.

Answer (score 0):

To get the matching objects, use `Array.filter()`, like this:

```js
const matches = myObjectArray.filter(obj => obj.email === 'x');
const firstMatch = matches[0];
```

To get just the plans, use `Array.map()`, like this:

```js
const plans = myObjectArray.filter(obj => obj.email === 'x').map(obj => obj.plan);
const firstPlan = plans[0];
```